# Angular4 ng-if condition whether select type of "input" or "select"

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-directives

i am new in angular, i am trying to use ng-if condition whether we select type=input or type=select, if we select type=select then select html will be render, otherwise input type will be render
Here is my code

```
    template: `<div *ngIf="type='input'">
                    <div class='investecField textField'>
                        <div class='investecFieldIn'>
                            <label>
                                <span>{{value}}</span>
                                <input type="text" value="{{valueInput}}">
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>`
                +
                `<div *ngIf="type='select'">
                    <div class='investecField selectField'>
                        <div class='investecFieldIn'>
                            <label>
                                <span>{{selectValue}}</span>
                                <strong><i class='fa fa-sort-desc' aria-hidden='true'></i></strong>
                                <select>
                                    <option></option>
                                    <option>Option 1</option>
                                    <option>Option 2</option>
                                    <option>Option 3</option>
                                </select>
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>`

})

export class investecFieldComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input()
    set selectValue(name: string) {

    };
    @Input() value: string;
    @Input() valueInput: string;


    constructor(private elem: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer2) {

    }
    ngOnInit() {

    }

}
```

And in html it is:

```
<investec-field [ngIf]="type=='input'"
                                    value="User Name"
                                    valueInput="">
                    </investec-field>
```

But i got an error in console
Error: Template parse errors:
Parser Error: Bindings cannot contain assignments at column 6 in [type='input'] in ng:///AppModule/investecFieldComponent.html@0:5 ("]*ngIf="type='input'">

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use **`===`** for checking  in your template

```
`<div *ngIf="type==='input'">
```

Comment: i used it. issue has been resolved. But nothing is showing on screen
http://prntscr.com/hvuqpv see this link